# How to programmatically check if user is member of a AD group within a SharePoint group?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint group called `SiteCollection Visitors`. In the Active Directory i have 3 nested AD Groups:

The AD group `ADGroup_L1`  has the member `ADGroup_L1_L2`  has the member `ADGroup_L1_L2_L3`.

In the AD group `ADGroup_L1_L2_L3` i have a user called `Adam`. Also this AD group is added to the SharePoint group `SiteCollection Visitors`.

Now i want to check programmatically from my SharePoint solution, if the user `Adam`, which is currently logged on to the SharePoint system, is member of the SP Group `SiteCollection Visitors`. He is not directly added to the group only through the nested ADGroup called `ADGroup_L1_L2_L3`. Is this possible in the SP Object Model?

Answer (score -1):

You can check to find the AD Group through SharePoint Object model.
And then loop over the AD group to find if user belong to the AD group.

Comment: But in an enterprise environment with many nested ad groups and many ad groups in sharepoint groups wouldnt this be a expensie operation?

Comment: AD is optimized to read so don't worry (windows (server) and all other connected consumers also read a lot). Writing and updating is far more expensive.